# Countable sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3...$ be a countable sequence of sets such that $A_i \sim \mathbb{R}$ for each $i$, show that the union of the sequence is similar to $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt: $A_i \sim [i-1,i)$ for each $i$  if each the sequence was pairwise disjoint, we would have that the union is similar to a subset $\mathbb{R}$. May I have hints on how to proceed?

Comment: What does the relation $\sim$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that similar means "having the same cardinality".
Your argument should work, assuming that you have proven that $ \mathbb{R} \sim [i-1,i) $. Then, this gives you a surjective function from $ [0, +\infty) $ to the union of the sequence, which means $ \mathbb{R} $ is at least as big as the union. And since any term of the sequence is at least as big as $ \mathbb{R} $, then the union is at least as big as $ \mathbb{R} $.
So we conclude that the union has the same size as $ \mathbb{R} $.

Comment: What if the sets aren't disjoint?

Comment: @topologicalmagician If the sets aren't disjoint then the surjective function from $ [0,+\infty) $ to the union will not be injective. But I only need it to be surjective to show that $ \mathbb{R} $ is at least as big as the union.

Comment: @topologicalmagician The thing is that every $A_i$ is similar to $\mathbb{R}$ by hypothesis, so the union $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ is surely big enough to be similar to $\mathbb{R}$